# HTTP 2.0 Delphi - доступна ли возможность подключаться к сайтам через idHTTP

Tags: delphi, https, ssl, indy, idhttp

Есть хостинг GIF-файлов: https://gifyu.com
Раньше он работал по http протоколу, но перешёл на https.
Попытки подключиться через `idHTTP` компонент с подключённым `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` успеха не принесли, отображается Exception:

> READ_BYTES:alert internal error.

Судя по заголовкам браузера, хостинг теперь работает с HTTP/2.0.
Предполагаю, что в этом и есть причина ошибки подключения.

Есть ли какой-то способ подключиться к хостингу через `idHTTP` по протоколу `HTTP/2.0`?
Или, возможно, есть другие способы подключиться по HTTPS к хостингу?

Comment: Если у вас IDE >XE7 попробуйте подключаться через System.Net.HttpClient.THttpClient. Не нужно будет мучаться с этими dll'ками

Comment: @ms301, действительно, спасибо, с `NetHTTPClient` работает отлично, даже редиректы по 302 обрабатывает. Получается, что idHTTP никак не поддерживает HTTP/2.0 или причина всё же в другом?

Comment: Попробуй руками обновить Инди. Загугли где взять его с СВН, скачай, и установи.

Comment: @rareMax - у меня он включён в комплект XE10, являясь более-менее новой версией среды. Пытался искать в сети по словам HTTP 2.0 и Indy. Не нашёл. Вряд ли есть обновление и вряд ли оно поможет.

Comment: На тему HTTP 2.0: `NetHTTPClient` отправляет запросы по HTTP 1.1 и они проходят. Значит причина была всё же не в HTTP 2.0, а настройках SSL или Indy, но не ясно каких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через `NetHTTPClient`. Долгое время сервер не хотел с ним работать. Оказалось, для такого компонента нужно вручную задавать идентификатор границы (boundary). После добавления строки ниже всё отлично заработало.

`NetHTTPClient1.ContentType:='multipart/form-data; boundary='+MultiData.Boundary;`

Единственный минус: компонент не поддерживает прогресс аплоада (индикацию загрузки файла на сервер). Сколько ни бился над решением, не нашёл реализации.

В остальном всем спасибо большое за помощь.
`SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host)` не проверял, но если как-нибудь доберусь, тоже постараюсь не забыть отписаться.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался как-то с проблемой, когда сайт поменял корневой сертификат на сертификат Cloudflare или что-то в этом духе:) Тогда перестало работать подключение по https. Попробуйте вот так:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Classes, IdHTTP, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders, IdCTypes;

type
  TCustomIdHTTP = class(TIdHTTP)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  private
    procedure OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL; const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT; const AType, AMsg: String);
  end;

{ TCustomIdHTTP }

constructor TCustomIdHTTP.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  with IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL do begin
    OnStatusInfoEx := Self.OnStatusInfoEx;
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1];
  end;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

procedure TCustomIdHTTP.OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL; const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT;
  const AType, AMsg: String);
begin
  SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host);
end;
//////////////////

var
  MyHTTP: TCustomIdHTTP;
begin
  MyHTTP := TCustomIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  // Your normal Indy HTTP code here
  MyHTTP.Free;
end.
```

Comment: Евгений, спасибо, попробую проверить. Судя по конструктору, у вас `OnStatusInfoEx := Self.OnStatusInfoEx` добавляется к обычным настройкам SSL? Т.е. именно из-за него подключение снова заработало? Ещё пугает монструозность строки `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host)` - сложно предположить что конкретно в ней происходит.

Comment: На самом деле я этот код посмотрел где-то в другом ответе у буржуев. Особо времени не было, чтобы досконально разобраться как работает `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host)`, но работает:)

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли какой-то способ подключиться к хостингу через idHTTP по протоколу HTTP/2.0?

Нет, на текущий момент Indy не умеет работать с этим протоколом.

Но у разработчиков есть на этот счёт планы: [Add support for HTTP 2.0](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/163)